# strange leak in instruments

Tags: iphone

When a luch instruments i have a leak that appear in the code below. where is the leak please ????

```
 - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [NavBarStyles sharedInstance].navStyle = @"navBarImage.png";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:16/255.0 green:160/255.0 blue:177/255.0 alpha:1.0];


    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: What exactly line shows memory leak here?

Comment: I think setting tintColor for navigationBar would leak.

Comment: i have in instruments in the leaked blocks : UIDeviceRGBColor and in the stack trace it show me any methos of my class but i think that it is in the line : self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383090/ios-4-3-uinavigationbar-tintcolor-leaks user said he reported to Apple. Yeah I have the same issue. Would be interested to see if someone has any working solution.

Comment: yes i have seen this post. i am working also in 4.3

Comment: Is this on the device or simulator? Try running and checking for leaks on the device. Sometimes things will leak in the simulator, but work fine on the device. (There's a case of this with AVFoundation)

Comment: With iOS 7, I've found that converting method calls from [UIColor colorWithRed...] to [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed...] caused my memory leak problems with Instruments to disappear.