# Obj-C, profiler allocation warning, how to understand them?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, profiling

I'm trying to figure out why profiler is giving me this error.
I'm autoreleasing my class instance.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong ?

[image]

Comment: I have had memory leaks when I set tintColor for navigationBar of Nav Controller. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383090/ios-4-3-uinavigationbar-tintcolor-leaks there are other people who complained about same. Hope it helps

Comment: The code: `[ap setColor:screen:con_Nav_tint:addi_None]` makes no sense wrt Objective-C naming/coding conventions and may be causing inaccurate messages.

Comment: CocoaFu why, it compiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are autoreleasing 'ap',but do you also autorelease the 'UIColor' object returned by 'ap setColor ...'? (that should be done inside your 'ap setColor...' method, which is not posted in your question.)

Comment: How do I release my UIColor I have.... `    if ([retColor isEqualToString:@"CLEAR"]) {
        return [UIColor clearColor];
    } else {
        return [UIColor colorWithHexString:retColor];
    }`

Comment: mmm, in that case you don't have to release it as it's autoreleased already when returned from `UIColor` class methods. The problem is elsewhere, sorry...